# How to pass JQuery deferred paramaters correctly?

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

This is my jQuery code. I basically am grabbing some coordinates based on IP and then retrieving some records for the location. The problem I have is that the parameters retrieved from the first ajax call are unavailable to the second ajax call. I am new to deferred's and don't really understand why this is not working? I left some comments in the code as questions and where the problem is. A complete answer would explain what I am missing and why it matters. I am trying to wrap my head around this to make my code cleaner versus nesting the calls.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#button').on('click', function() {
    //if the first call is successful then run the second function
    //is done the correct thing to use here?
    getLocation().done(getRecords);
  });
  //this works fine as i get the coordinates
  function getLocation() {
    return $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'http://ipinfo.io/json',
      success: function(response) {
        var coordinates = response.loc.split(',');
        return coordinates;
      }
    });
  }

  function getRecords(coordinates) {
   return $.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'some url',
      data: {
        //this does not work as coordinates are undefined
        lat : coordinates[0],
        lon : coordinates[1],
      },
      success: function(response) {
        //do more stuff
      }
    });
  }

});
```

Comment: `coordinates` shouldn't be undefined. Are you sure it isn't actually equal to `response` from the success callback?

Comment: @KevinB I will check again to verify.

Comment: @KevinB The entire object is still present from the first ajax call, which was making coordinates undefined because they are not directly accessible variables. So what should this look like? Also is done the correct thing to call?

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question?  It's a legitimate question.

Comment: @Smeegs I agree. I have two downvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this work like you expect, you would need to remove `success:` and instead use `.then` so that you can pass on the value to the next promise in the chain.

```
function getLocation() {
  return $.ajax({
    dataType: "json",
    url: 'http://ipinfo.io/json'/*,
    success: function(response) {
      var coordinates = response.loc.split(',');
      return coordinates;
    }*/
  }).then(function (response) {
    var coordinates = response.loc.split(',');
    return coordinates;
  });
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly and makes alot more sense about how to use then to send the "success". Would you have changed anything else in my code to make it more efficient? Once again I am learning and so anything that makes me more effective I am open to.

Comment: Not really, other than not using such a generic id value `'#button'`

Comment: Good note. I planned on changing that. It was just to get a functional example up.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem that the`success` handler's result is not passed to the `done` handler. The original `response` is passed. You may've wanted `then`.

There's absolutely no reason to use jQuery in *2016*, though.

Answer (score -2):

Your function calls are backward. Try:

```
getRecords(getLocation());
```

Comment: or not. getLocation returns a promise, not the coordinates.

Comment: It still passes the results into the getRecords function which can then be parsed out.

Comment: No, it doesn't, the results are still inside the promise. You would have to use .then(function() {...}) on it to get to the results. (or .done,) but then you'd be right back in the current situation that the OP is in, because you'd have the response rather than the coordinates.